# Why i need to have DevExpress Installed to use XPF.Core

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, devexpress

We are using DevExpress in my team to develop WPF application. We have limited licences but this is not a problem because you can ask someone to add DLL et work on a project without DevExpress installed.

But, because i need the combobox edit control from XPF.CORE, i saw that i need to have Dev Express installed to build the code.
SO the issue is no one can compile the code if they don't have devexpress installed.
Is someone got this issue before and find a solution?Is DevExpress.Xpf.Core the pnly one DLL with the issue?

Comment: You have to buy a dev express license for each developer.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the licensing terms of DevExpress if you copy the assemblies around. From [their licensing FAQ](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/LicensingFAQ.xml):

> **Is your license on a per-developer basis?** Does each developer using your products require a license? 
>   **Yes**. Each developer that uses our products must have their own license. We don't license per machine, per server, or demand any royalties or run-time fees. For more information, refer to our End-User License Agreement. If you have a testing team and they need to compile the application, then those testers will also each need a license. Testers who just test the completed, compiled application (that is, use it much as an end-user does) do not need a license.

Now, when you say:

> We have limited licences *but this is not a problem because you can ask someone to add DLL et work on a project without DevExpress installed.*

then it might not be a problem for you but do you realize that they can only dedicate so much resources to their product development if they get paid for what they deliver? I'd say take it up with your managers and convince them that the right way is to buy more licenses or cut down on the number of people working on the product because otherwise they are facilitating illegal use of the product.

Comment: We are worked like that because several developer can work a 1 project but different part. One work on devexpress xaml control and the other one work only in c# code.

Comment: But you will still need a licence for every developer if you want them to work on a project involving devexpress.

Comment: Yes i agree. I will see with my manager but i heard before it was a budget issue or something and that no all developer will need to use it.
But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was about the default theme of the application.

> Starting with version 16.1, applications with DevExpress components
>   use the Office2016White theme by default, and the
>   DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.Office2016White library has to be deployed to a
>   client machine.

If you don't want to use the Office2016White theme in your application, specify a theme of your choice in the application constructor using the *DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ApplicationThemeHelper.ApplicationThemeName* property or set the *ApplicationThemeHelper.UseLegacyDefaultThemeproperty* to **true**.

[Reference - DevExpress QA thread](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T406146/deployment-of-wpf-application-requires-devexpress-xpf-themes-office2016white-v16-1-dll)